# Calling lambda/std::function in main UI thread from a background thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt

Im my mainthread, I have a Qt window running, which is calling my background thread (network service) and is eventually expecting responses which should be reflected in the UI:

```
// runs in main (GUI) thread
void QTServer::onButtonClick(){
    srv->request(msg, 
        [this]
           (std::shared_ptr<message> msg){
              this->ui.txtResponse->setText("received a response" + msg.data());
            });
}
```

The network service is as follows:

```
std::function<void(std::shared_ptr<message>)> delegate_;

void NetworkService::request(message& msg,std::function<void(std::shared_ptr<message> msg)> fn)
{
    // send the request to the socket and store the callback for later
    // ...
    this->delegate_ = fn;
}

void NetworkService::onResponseReceived(std::shared_ptr<message> responseMsg)
{
    // is called from the background thread (service)
    // Here I would like to call the lambda function that the service stored somewhere (currently as an std::func member)

    // psuedo: call In Main Thread: delegate_(responseMsg);
}
```

How does that work? Does it even work?

I know that you can use `QMetaObject::invokeMethod(this, "method", Qt::QueuedConnection` to call a function in the mainthread, so I tried the following:

```
void NetworkService::onResponseReceived(std::shared_ptr<message> responseMsg)
{
    QMetaObject::invokeMethod(this, "runInMainThread", Qt::QueuedConnection, QGenericArgument(), Q_ARG(std::function<void(std::shared_ptr<message>)>, delegate_));
}
```

How do I pass the responseMsg here as an argument for _delegate?

```
 void QTServer::runInMainThread(std::function<void(std::shared_ptr<message>)> f) {
    f(); 
}
```

How to get rid of "No function with these arguments" error?

Answer (score 1):

remove QGenericArgument() - it's internal helper class.
also you have to register your own types in order to use Q_ARG or send data as void* then cast it back.

```
Q_ARG(void*, delegate_)
```

2nd question - f is function which takes one argument - std::shared_ptr, and f() - call without argument, so add default argument

Comment: hmm, it says "no constructor available" if I try `Q_ART(void*, delegate_)`

Comment: pass address Q_ARG(void*, &delegate_), then use reinterpret_cast<void(std::shared_ptr<message>)*>

Answer (score -1):

I believe the recommended way for what you are trying to achieve in QT is by using signals and slots in combination with QThread. For example:

```
MyObject * myObject = new MyObject(); //your worker
QThread * myThread = new QThread(); //your thread
myObject->moveToThread(myThread);

QObject::connect(myThread, SIGNAL(started()), myObject, SLOT(startWorking())); //when thread starts, invoke the working method
QObject::connect(myObject, SIGNAL(stoppedWorking()), this, SLOT(stoppedWorking())); //when worker signals it finished, invoke slot in main

QObject::connect(myObject, SIGNAL(stoppedWorking()), myThread, SLOT(quit())); //quit the thread when worker signals that it finished
QObject::connect(myObject, SIGNAL(gproxyExiting()), gproxy, SLOT(deleteLater())); //cleanup
QObject::connect(myThread, SIGNAL(finished()), myThread, SLOT(deleteLater())); //cleanup
```

This way the whole lifecycle is managed automatically for you and you can define whatever signals inside the worker and slots on the main thread to communicate with each other.